# Making pyinstaller --onefile install portable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a cli application using pyinstaller (currently for macos).  My initial impression on reading the pyinstaller documentation is that I would be able to bundle all necessary files into a single file when the `--onefile` option is used.

However, when I bundled the file with the following command and tested it on someone else's pc, the resulting binary had a dependency to a path on my PC (specific to the bundled venv configuration). (*Locally the bundled onefile binary runs fine... I assume because the path dependency is present*)

```
pyinstaller mycli.py
```

Am I miss-understanding what pyinstaller does?  Or, is there something special I need to do to make the resulting bundle portable?

> Using python3 btw

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to identify the missing files (in case of libraries: `dll`, `pyd`) that need to be bundeled with your exe.

These files need to be added to spec file, as described in the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle).